# Query to find attendance count per month per student ID

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to create a Oracle Query for the below scenario:-

I need a query to get the number of times the student has attended the classes per location per month .We need to use the access dates columns from the table to find the count of attendance.

We need to find the count of the times each student has attended the classes in month of January ,February, March,...  from each location. The student can also swipe from different locations as well based on below sample data.

The final query should tell us: ID , **location[with all letters in Capital] and no US in suffix** and the count of access per month.

I tried the below query but it didnt work:-

```
select ID,SUBSTRING(t.location,1,(INSTR(t.location,',')-1) as COUNTY from tablename t group by Access Dates;
```

Can someone please suggest how to rectify or suggest the oracle query to achieve below output? I am little new to Oracle .Kindly suggest.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
ID:  COUNTY  Attendancecount  Month
101  NEWYORK       21            JAN
102  NEWJERSEY     24            JAN
103  LOSANGELES    20            JAN
104  LOSANGELES    27            JAN
101  NEWYORK       25            FEB
102  NEWJERSEY     18            FEB
103  LOSANGELES    21            FEB
104  LOSANGELES    21            FEB
```

The sample data looks like below:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
ID   location        Access dates
101  newyork,USA      01-Jan-2021
102  newjersey,USA    02-Jan-2021
103  newyork,USA      02-Jan-2021
104  Losangeles,USA   01 Jan 2021
101  newyork,USA    04 Jan 2021
102  newJersey,USA    04 Jan 2021
103  newyork,USA      05-Jan-2021
104  Losangeles,USA   05 Jan 2021
101  newyork,USA    05 Jan 2021
102  newJersey,USA    05 Jan 2021
```

Regards
Hari

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain what "it didnt work" means in detail.

Comment: Hint: to get a count of records, use the aggregate function ```COUNT```. There are plenty of examples on the web that should allow you to figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: The query which i tried  doesnt work and I dont know how to seggregate based on delimiters and how to find the count of attendance based on access dates.The logic is not striking

Comment: @KoenLostrie : I used count but it still doesnt work with having clause to give conditions.Can you send some similar examples i will try .I am new to oracle so i am not aware

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_repalce` and `upper` as follows:

```
select ID,
       upper(regexp_replace(t.location,'(,USA)$') as COUNTY,
       count(*) as attendance_count,
       to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'MON') as month_ 
  from tablename t 
 group by ID,
       upper(regexp_replace(t.location,'(,USA)$'),
       to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'MON');
```

Comment: If i need to extract year can i use : to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'YEAR') Year.Please advice. For month we use MON what is param for YEAR

Comment: You can use `YYYY`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your data is in order. You have different types of formatting in Access dates, please correct it and make sure this column is datatype as DATE. Second,
remove spaces from column headers. Now please try below:

```
SELECT
t.ID
,UPPER(SUBSTR(t.location,1,INSTR(t.location,',')-1)) COUNTY
,count(t.ACCESSDATES) ATTENDANCECOUNT
,to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'MON') MONTH
from tablename t
group by 
t.ID
,UPPER(SUBSTR(t.location,1,INSTR(t.location,',')-1))
,to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'MON')
;
```

Comment: If i need to extract year can i use : to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'YEAR') Year.Please advice

Comment: Hi, you should use: to_char(t.ACCESSDATES,'YYYY') . You will find more info on formats in here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212